# Mongodb.com how to confirm if a collection is correctly setup as a Time Series Collection?

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I try to create a Time Series Collection on Mongodb.com like this:

```
//create timeseries collection with expiry
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var db = client.db("abc");
      db.createCollection("events",{
        timeseries: {
          timeField: "timestamp",
          metaField: "metadata",
          granularity: "seconds"          
        },
        expireAfterSeconds: ...
      }, function(err, res) {
        if (err && err.codeName != "NamespaceExists") {
          console.log("error creating collection", err.codeName)
          console.log("error creating collection", res)
        }else{
          console.log("Collection events created!", res);        
        }
        collection = db.collection("events");
        console.log("collection", collection);
      });        
  });

//insert timeseries data
var date = moment.utc(json.created_date).toDate();    
var data = {
      "metadata": json,
      "timestamp": date,
      "price": price
}
const insertResult = await collection.insertOne(data);
```

I can that a collection is created and data is increasing. But I remember last time Mongodb.com will show "time series" label somewhere near the collection overview page, but now I don't see it anymore. There is no way for me to confirm if this collection is correctly configured as a Time series collection? How can I confirm?

[image]

Comment: You can check by getting the `collStats` - [collStats.timeseries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#mongodb-data-collStats.timeseries) sub-document confirms that.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks that works, turns out it is really not a timeseries database. you can put it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

```
const collectionName = "events";
db.getCollectionInfos({name:collectionName}, {nameOnly: true });
```

above code should give you the name and type of your collection "events"

reference - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/#example

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/#check-if-a-collection-is-of-type-time-series